# Gradle Sync Issues when run react native app from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I tried to run my react native app from android studio, but I got this error messages

org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open cp_settings remapped class cache for 41bc8mnmvai79ppb5x860ykf1

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

I've tried the steps from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial to run my application

Comment: You may want to try cleaning the gradle cache.